# NGINX routing question - I've spent some hours on this to no luck yet

Tags: nginx, redirect, routes

I've spent hours on multiple message boards and forums looking for this config pattern in NGINX. I want a subdomain to get redirected to port 8080 before the catch-all grabs everything else that comes into the domain, including all other subdomains, and points it at 443.

The 443 redirect already works perfectly. Any and all help would be appreciated thank you.

I have adminer.server.app that I want to goto HTTP://adminer.server.app (it really goes to 8080 after NGINX would do it's thing)

Again, all other traffic is taken care of so far.

Here is a snippet of my conf file:

```
server {
listen      80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name server.app www.server.app;

location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

#for certbot challenges (renewal process)
location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /data/letsencrypt;
}
}

#https://adminer.server.app
server {
listen 8080;

server_name adminer.server.app;
server_tokens off;
resolver 8.8.8.8;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
}
}

#https://server.app
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name server.app;

server_tokens off;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/certs/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/certs/privkey.pem;

ssl_buffer_size 8k;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_tickets off;

# OCSP stapling
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8;

return 301 https://www.server.app$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Should that `listen 8080` be `listen 80`?

Comment: Thank you Richard, I tried both... but the listen line holds the incoming port, and the proxy points it to the internal port that responds to the Docker container. I'll add a pic of my Docker settings.

Comment: I tried attaching a pic, no luck, I don't know how to do that... here's my Docker settings... the PHP MyAdmin is what I want to reach...

Comment: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.20-aarch64 172.25.0.3  3306:3306 
production phpmyadmin 172.25.0.2 8080:8080  administratorsportainer/portainer-ee 172.17.0.2  8000:8000  9443:9443  
production-nginx-container nginx:latest 172.24.0.2 443:443  80:80

Comment: production phpmyadmin 172.25.0.2 8080:8080

Comment: I see pics aren't desired or allowed...

Comment: A thought Richard... could I have listen 80 on the adminer.server.app as well as listen 80 on server.app?  I tried that too, but maybe I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can bring the phpmyadmin up by using my IP:8080, so at the moment, this isn't critical. I'm not going to expose it after I'm done configuring the MySQL anyway. Closing request for help.

A few months ago I started using Cloudflare (2023) and as far as providing a function similar to a proxy, it is far better at exposing the routing to the external world. And handles as many subdomains as I want to use.